# JavaScript algorithms: find starting and ending indices of consecutively repeated chars from a string

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I wanted to function a function that does this:

```js
const input =“hellooooloo”;
const results = getRepeated(input);
console.log(results) // [(2,3), (4,7), (9,10)]
```

It returns an array of arrays of indices of the starting and ending index of consecutively repeated chars from a string.

Here is my attempt, it is a O(n^2). I wonder if there is a more elegant and efficient way of achieving this

```js
const input = 'hellooooloo'; 
const results = getRepeated(input); // // [(2,3), (4,7), (9,10)]

function getRepeated(string) {
    const results = []
    if(string.length < 2) return results
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
        if(i > 1 && string[i] === string[i-1]) {
            continue
        }
        let startIndex = i
        let endIndex = i
        for(let j = i + 1; j < string.length; j++) {
            if(string[i] === string[j]) {
                endIndex = j
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        if(startIndex !== endIndex) {
            results.push([startIndex, endIndex])
        }
    }

    return results
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is not `O(n^2)`, it is `O(n)`. (Well, actually, it is both.) It is because of the if ... then continue logic that you have on lines 8 and 9. The inner loop (j loop) iterates at most for `O(n)` steps in total. Because, if the j loop proceeds for, say m steps, then for the next m steps the outer loop will take the continue branch on line 9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression: match and capture one character, then backreference that same character as many times as you can. Perform a global regex match on the string. Take all the matches and map them to an array of their index, and their index plus the length of the match:

```js
const getRepeated = str => [...str.matchAll(/(.)\1+/g)]
  .map(({ index, 0: match }) => [index, index + match.length - 1]);

const input = "hellooooloo";
const results = getRepeated(input);
console.log(results) // [(2,3), (4,7), (9,10)]
```

This is `O(n)`.

The regular expression means:

- `(.)` - Match any character, put it in a capture group
- `\1+` - Repeat the same character matched by that capture group one or more times

Eg, for the example input here, you'll get the following matches:

```
[
  { 0: 'll', 1: 'l', index: 2 },
  { 0: 'oooo', 1: 'o', index: 4 },
  { 0: 'oo', 1: 'o', index: 9 },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You couldr educe the array of characters and check if the last character is equal to the actual and adjust the second index of the last index pair.

Otherwise check if the actual character is equal to the next character and create a new result set.

```js
const
    getRepeated = ([...array]) => array.reduce((r, c, i, a) => {
        if (a[i - 1] === c) r[r.length - 1][1] = i;
        else if (c === a[i + 1]) r.push([i]);
        return r;
    }, []),
    input = 'hellooooloo',
    result = getRepeated(input); // [[2, 3], [4, 7], [9, 10]]

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more solution in O(n).

```
function getRepeated(string) {
const map = new Map();
const pairs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    const char = string[i];
    const prevChar = string[i - 1];
    if (!map.has(char)) {
        const indexes = map.get(prevChar);
        if (indexes?.end) {
            pairs.push(indexes)
            map.delete(prevChar)
        }
        map.set(char, {start: i})
    } else {
        map.get(char).end = i;
    }
}
const lastVal = Array.from(map.values()).pop();
return lastVal?.end ? [...pairs, lastVal] : pairs;
```

}

```
console.log(findRepeatingIndex("hellooooloo")); // [ { start: 2, end: 3 }, { start: 4, end: 7 }, { start: 9, end: 10 } ]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).