# JavaScript Algorithms: implement a function to separate a string using a dictionary

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to write a function that does this

```js
const dict = {hi: true, hello: true, world: true}
const string = 'helloworld'
const string2 = 'helloworldhi'
const string3 = 'helloworldh'
spaceSeparetor(string, dict) // hello world
spaceSeparetor(string2, dict) // hello world hi
spaceSeparetor(string3, dict) // ''  empty string because `h` is not present in the `dict`
```

so the function is separating the string with a white space using the words in the dictionary. It doesn't have to use all of the words in the dictionary. But if there is a word in the string that is not present in the dict, we return an empty string.

Here is my attempt:

```js
function spaceSeparetor(string, dict) {
    let count = 0
    let chars = ''
    const result = []
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        chars += string[i] 
        if(dict[chars]) {
            count += chars.length
            result.push(chars)
            chars = ''
        }
    }

    return string.length === count ?  result.join(' ') : ''
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some cases your code would not find a solution. For instance if you would add the word "hell" as the first property of your dict:

```
const dict = {hell: true, hi: true, hello: true, world: true}
```

...all three outputs will be empty.

This happens because your algorithm will then first match "hell", after which it does not find a word that starts with "o", and so it fails. The conclusion is that a greedy algorithm does not always find a solution.

To fix this, implement backtracking (with recursion):

```js
const dict = {hell: true, hi: true, hello: true, world: true};
//            ^^^^^^^^^^
const string = 'helloworld';
const string2 = 'helloworldhi';
const string3 = 'helloworldh';
console.log(spaceSeparator(string, dict)); // hello world
console.log(spaceSeparator(string2, dict)); // hello world hi
console.log(spaceSeparator(string3, dict)); // ''

function spaceSeparator(string, dict) {
  if (!string) return []; // success!
  for (let i = 1; i <= string.length; i++) {
    let chars = string.slice(0, i);
    if (dict[chars]) {
      let rest = spaceSeparator(string.slice(i), dict); // recur
      if (rest) return [chars, ...rest];
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Comment: exactly! Backtracking is the solution I am looking for here.

Comment: Btw could you take a look at my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607725/implement-a-function-in-javascript-to-determine-if-a-word-can-be-formed-from-ano. I feel it might be solved with backtracking too.

Comment: Marked. could you take a look at this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590804/javascript-algorithms-find-starting-and-ending-indices-of-consecutively-repeate. See if it can be solved with backtracking.

Comment: I marked it now. Please take a look at the other two questions. Thanks!

Comment: I see a comment under your first question, which you didn't answer to...

Comment: Ok I will reply shortly. Btw I added memoization on top of your solution. It seems to be working but not sure if I have covered all of the test cases. Could you take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/k0xuc5fj/1/ and let me know if there is something wrong with it

Comment: You never populate `results` in that fiddle. But this comment section is not intended to do code review. So please, if you have a new question, post it as one after doing enough testing and getting stuck on an issue. If however you have *working* code and need advise on efficiency and code style, then ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion... Can I ask you one last question on here? Because I don't think I can reopen a new question just for this follow up question but I am really curious about how you managed to tell that an intuitive greedy algorithm couldn't cover all cases for this question, and as a result we had to use dfs + backtracking? Like I understand we can always try to come up with a counter example but is there some pattern you can derive from these kind questions that can come in handy when deciding on using greedy vs. backtracking?

Comment: No, there is no generic pattern I can point to. I think this was a matter of intuition. And you create good intuition by practice. So I would advise to go to code challenges sites and solve problems, many problems, and then read what others did to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks pretty reasonable. You can simplify it a bit by removing the `count` variable by checking to see whether the `chars` string being constructed has any characters in it. If it does, then the string does not get fully matched by the desired pattern:

```js
const dict = {hi: true, hello: true, world: true}
const string = 'helloworld'
const string2 = 'helloworldhi'
const string3 = 'helloworldh'
console.log(spaceSeparetor(string, dict)) // hello world
console.log(spaceSeparetor(string2, dict)) // hello world hi
console.log(spaceSeparetor(string3, dict)) // ''  empty string because `h` is not present in the `dict`

function spaceSeparetor(string, dict) {
  let chars = ''
  const result = []
  for (const char of string) {
    chars += char
    if (dict[chars]) {
      result.push(chars)
      chars = ''
    }
  }
  return chars ? '' : result.join(' ')
}
```

If you're looking for another approach, you could use a regular expression to match repeated occurrences of the `dict` keys. Execute a global match. If all the matches, put together, produces the input string, return the joined matches:

```js
const dict = {hi: true, hello: true, world: true}
const string = 'helloworld'
const string2 = 'helloworldhi'
const string3 = 'helloworldh'
console.log(spaceSeparetor(string, dict)) // hello world
console.log(spaceSeparetor(string2, dict)) // hello world hi
console.log(spaceSeparetor(string3, dict)) // ''  empty string because `h` is not present in the `dict`

function spaceSeparetor(string, dict) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(Object.keys(dict).join('|'), 'g');
  const match = string.match(pattern);
  return match?.join('') === string ? match.join(' ') : '';
}
```

For a couple examples:

`helloworldhi` produces a match array of `['hello', 'world', 'hi']`. Joined together, this matches the input string, so it passes (and the return value can be the joined match array)

`helloworldh` produces a match array of `['hello', 'world']`. Joined together, this does not match the input string, so it fails.

Comment: yea indeed I don't need to use a separate variable for the count. thanks for the answer!