# Implement a function in JavaScript to determine if a word can be formed from another word by removing repeated letters

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to implement a function in JavaScript called `canBeFormed` that does this:

```js
const string1 = 'hellooooolooo'
const string2 = 'hellolo'
canBeFormed(string1, string2) // true since by deleting the repeated chars 'o' and 'l' we can form the word 'hellolo'
```

So if `string2` can be formed by `string1` if `string1` remove some duplicate chars then we return `true`

I cannot seem to come up with a workable solution to this problem. Can someone give this a shot?

Btw, someone mentioned that this could be solved by dfs + backtracking. Can someone give that approach a try?

To clarify, this function return `true` if it can form a word from the second string provided by removing one or more repeated letters.

So `canBeFormed("heellolo", "hellooooolooo")` will return `false`. `canBeFormed("abc", "ac")` will return `false`

Comment: For clarification of your intentions: `canBeFormed("heellolo")` should return `false`, because there was no `ee` in the original `"hellooooolooo"`?

Comment: Also, if the longer string has a **non**-duplicate letter that does not match, should we not be allowed to delete it?

Comment: Could you provide the expected result for `canBeFormed("abc", "ac")`, `canBeFormed("abbc", "ac")`, and `canBeFormed("ababc", "abc")`?

Comment: If the duplicate characters are not consecutive, can they still be deleted? This question is not clear.

Comment: Any reaction on these comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the function should return true if, and only when, the first string can be formed from the second by repeating (consecutively) some characters already present in the first.

The algorithm can be greedy and no backtracking is needed.

```js
function canBeFormed(a, b) {
    let i = 0;
    for (let ch of b) {
        if (ch !== a[i]) {
            // Skip duplicate letters in a
            while (a[i] === a[i-1]) {
                if (++i >= a.length) return false;
            }
            if (ch !== a[i]) return false;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    // Remaining characters should be duplicates
    while (a[i] === a[i-1]) {
        if (++i >= a.length) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(canBeFormed("hellooooollooo","hellolo")); // true
console.log(canBeFormed("abbcc", "abc")); // true
console.log(canBeFormed("aaabbb", "aaabb")); // true
console.log(canBeFormed("helloooolloo","heellolo")); // false
console.log(canBeFormed("abc", "ac")); // false
console.log(canBeFormed("abbc", "ac")); // false
console.log(canBeFormed("ababc", "abc")); // false
console.log(canBeFormed("abbcca", "abc")); // false
console.log(canBeFormed("aab", "aaab")); // false
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am wondering what is the defining characteristic of a question that makes one use greedy vs. dfs + backtracking? As you said this question can be solved with greedy, what do you think it needs to change so that we have to solve it with backtracking? I got this question from some other blog post and in that blog post it mentioned it should be solved with backtracking. Maybe there is some info missed in the description of the question... Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I can only go by the question you asked. As I mentioned in comments below your question, there are several things unclear in that question. It is up to you to clarify.

Comment: actually, I have updated my description to clarify the question. I understand that the current question might not warrant a backtracking solution. But I am genuinely curious how we can tweak the problem so the greedy solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You are asking us to design a question, but that is not what you ask in the question. Any way, even if you would ask that as a new question, I believe it will be closed, as it doesn't look to be on-topic for Stack Overflow. ...And, the comments I placed yesterday below your question are not clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:
weed out any duplicate from both string (using `reduce` to skip char repetitions)
and simply compare the resulting strings are the same or not.

```js
const string1 = 'hellooooolooo'
const string2 = 'hellolo'

const unique = s => Array.from(s).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[acc.length - 1] !== curr) return acc + curr
  return acc
}, "");

const canBeFormed = (str1, str2) => unique(str1) === unique(str2);

console.log(canBeFormed(string1, string2))
console.log(canBeFormed('helloo', 'hellolo'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
function canBeFormed(a, b) {
  let extraIndex = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (a[i + extraIndex] !== b[i]) {
      if (a[i + extraIndex] !== a[i + extraIndex - 1]) {
        return false;
      }
      let duplicateChar = a[i + extraIndex];
      while (a[i + extraIndex] !== b[i]) {
        if (a[i + extraIndex] !== duplicateChar) {
          return false;
        } else {
          extraIndex++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const string1 = 'hellooooolooo'
const string2 = 'hellolo'
console.log(
  canBeFormed(string1, string2)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is as follows

```js
function getCharFreq(str) {
  let charFreq = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!charFreq[str[i]]) {
      charFreq[str[i]] = 0;
    }
    charFreq[str[i]]++;
  }
  return charFreq;
}

function canBeFormed(str1, str2) {
  const charFreq1 = getCharFreq(str1);
  const charFreq2 = getCharFreq(str2);
  for (let key in charFreq2) {
    if (charFreq1[key] < charFreq2[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const string1 = 'hellooooolooo'
const string2 = 'hellolo'
console.log(
  canBeFormed(string1, string2)
)
```

Comment: Your solution fails on `canBeFormed('hellooolo', 'helloo')`. Note the last `l` (from `string1`) is missing from `string2`. Don't solely rely on frequency.. order matters as well

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the order also matters! Thanks for your reminder. 
I think it's better if the question provides more cases

Answer (score 0):

Here's my steps to solve it.

1.convert it into an array

2.weep out the duplicate

3.sort the array alphabetically

4.use include method to check

```js
const string1 = 'hellooooolooo'
const string2 = 'helloo'

// console.log(string1.includes(string2))

function removeDuplicate(string) {
  return string
    .split('')
    .filter((item, pos, self) => {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
    })
    .sort()
    .join('')
}

console.log(removeDuplicate(string1).includes(removeDuplicate(string2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on it:

```js
function canBeFormed(a,b){
  var a=a.split(""),b=b.split("");
  //console.log(a,b);
  for (var i=j=0; i<a.length; i++,j++){
 if(a[i]!==b[j] && a[i]!==b[--j]) break;
  }
  return [j==b.length,b.slice(0,i).join("")];
}
[["hellooooollooo","hellolo"],
 ["helloooolloo","heellolo"],
 ["wooorddd","word"]].map(([a,b])=>
console.log(canBeFormed(a,b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need a code that returns true if string2 can be formed using string1 and returns false if cannot?

```js
const createObj = (obj, word) => {
  [...word].forEach(str => {
    if (!obj[str]) {
      obj[str] = 0;
    }
    obj[str] = obj[str] + 1;
  });
  return obj;
};

const canBeFormed = (str1, str2) => {
  let obj1 = {};
  let obj2 = {};
  
  const strObj1 = createObj(obj1, str1);
  const strObj2 = createObj(obj2, str2);
  
  if (Object.keys(strObj1).length !== Object.keys(strObj2).length) {
    return false
  };
  
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.values(strObj2).length; i++) {
    if (Object.values(strObj1)[i] < Object.values(strObj2)[i]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
};

console.log(canBeFormed('hellooooolooo', 'hellolo')) // true
console.log(canBeFormed("heellolo", "hellooooolooo")) // false
console.log(canBeFormed("abc", "ac")) // false
```